# Closest projection to GeographicLib's Local Cartesian

Tags: coordinate-system, geographiclib

We are using the excellent GeographicLib https://sourceforge.net/projects/geographiclib/ in our application, a professional ship simulator. Our 3D scene is rendered using a Local Cartesian projection provided by this library.
But we need to use some GIS tools, including QGIS, to edit the scenario, but we don't known if there is an equivalent projection based on GDAL/PROJ.4. The best results was obtained with +proj=tmerc +ellips=wsg84 +k=0.99997 but It doesn't matches exactly. I tried ortho too, but it looks far than tmerc.

Does anyone know which GDAL/PROJ.4  is equivalent to that Local Cartesian?